# No logout/power-off option in Unity's power cog menu

Tags: unity, shutdown, logout, power-cog

After upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10, I don't have a logout/power-off option in the upper right menu. Is there a way to add it?

Comment: I should mention that Stack Exchange isn't conducive to flamewars, so the last bit of your post is going to do very little of interest. For what it's worth, though, you are welcome to form your own opinion.

Comment: My Dad just upgraded to 11.10 and the power cog has not shown up for him. How can he get it to show up?

Answer (score 4):

If you get this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJz4A.png]

(Clean Install, added gnome-panel, gnome-shell, and gnome-system-tools)

What actually works is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and then choosing Log out.

Answer (score 2):

There's a strange bug where the menu that has the session controls will actually crash, and disappear. If you open the dash and search for "log out," you will find the option you need.

[image]

The next time you log in, the session menu should be there at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

What theme are you using? There is a bug if you use a theme other than Ambiance or Radiance, the system status menu in the top right won't show.

I believe it is fixed if you install gnome-icon-theme-full. Log out and then log back in.

If that doesn't work, I recommend you stick with Ambiance or Radiance.